# Reactjs error Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError:

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the contents of an object, which is as follows:

```
{
number: "23445"
title: "this is the title"
body: "this is the body"
user:  { 
login: "xxxx",
id: 1706020
}
}
```

Basically, I query the API and it returns me the object, which I store in a state variable. I am then able to display the results of the API call using

```
<h2>
        Issue Details #{issue.number} {issue.title}
 </h2>
```

My issue is that when I'm trying to display the login, using the map method:

```
<p>
        {issue.user.length > 0  &&
        ({issue.user.map((person) => (
          <div key={person.id}>
            <p>{person.login}</p>
          </div>
        ))})
        }
        
      </p>
```

I get the error** Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/components/IssueDetails.jsx: Unexpected token, expected ","**

This is the line corresponding to `({issue.user.map((person) => (`

Comment: Have you tried searching for "message" in your codebase?

Comment: `&& ({issue.user.map(` These curly brackets aren't escaping from JSX back to plain javascript, because this spot of the code isn't JSX. Delete the `({` and matching `})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having `Object` in your JSON data, not a `Array of Objects`. Whereas `.map` function is built for mapping arrays.

Also, there is no field called `length` in object due to that, you cannot use it for checking the length unless you have `<Array<Object>>` but currently, you have shown only 1 Object.

A **easy** solution would be:

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/issue.json').then(res => { //Just fetched it from my local data that is placed in public folder.
            return res.json()
        }).then(data => setData(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {
                    data.user && // .length doesn't exist in your user object
                    [data.user].map((person) => ( // Applying array format when using .map
                        <div key={person.id}>
                            <p>{person.id}</p>
                            <p>{person.login}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }

            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

A **better** solution would be converting your `issue.json` to Array of Objects, something like this:

```json
   [
    {
      "number": "23445",
      "title": "this is the title",
      "body": "this is your first object",
      "user": {
        "login": "xxxx",
        "id": 1706020
      }
    },
    {
      "number": "23445",
      "title": "this is the title",
      "body": "this is your second object",
      "user": {
        "login": "xxxx",
        "id": 1706020
      }
    },
   ]
```

Comment: thanks, @margav. It works. Can you please clarify, the second solution; you mean duplicating the object to have an array?

Comment: When you have multiple objects like multiple user data, you create 1 array having all those objects. And then you can apply `.map` function to that array and get each item from it.